# Thread blocked forever when waits on lock operation

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, reentrantreadwritelock

I'm writing a java implementation for two-phase locking. So, I'm using Reentrant lock (ReadWrite lock). The problem is that when a thread executes the lock.readLock.lock() or lock.writeLock().lock() and the lock is already locked it stuck their forever even when the lock unlocked by using lock.readLock().unlock() or lock.writeLock().unlock(). So, it looks like the unlock doesn't wakeup the waiters!!!
here is the code that causes the problem:

```
class LockTable
{
//    /*******************************************************************************
//     * This class is used to represent an individual lock.
//     * @param tid     the id of the transaction holding the lock
//     * @param shared  whether the lock is shared (true) or exclusive (false)
//     */
//    void Lock (int tid, boolean shared)
//    {
//        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore (0);
//    } // Lock class

    /** Associative map of locks held by transactions of the form (key = oid, value = lock)
     */
    private HashMap<Integer,MyLock> locks;

    public LockTable(){
        locks= new HashMap<Integer,MyLock>();

    }

    /*******************************************************************************
     * Acquire a shared/read lock on data object oid.
     * @param tid  the transaction id
     * @param oid  the data object id
     */
    void rl (int tid, int oid) throws InterruptedException
    {

        MyLock lock=null;
        boolean wait = false;
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                lock = locks.get(oid);             // find the lock

                if((lock != null) && (lock.lock.isWriteLocked())){

                   wait = true;

                  // System.out.println(locks.get(oid).shared);
                }

                if(lock == null){
                 lock = new MyLock(tid, true);
                 lock.lock.readLock().lock();
                 lock.readers.add(tid);
                 locks.put(oid, lock);
              }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());        // lock not found, so oid is not locked;
            } // try
        }//synch


        if (wait){

            System.out.println("Transaction " + tid + " is waiting..");
            Main.g.addEdge(tid, lock.tid);
                    if(Main.g.hasCycle())
                        restart(tid);

            //to exclude the restarted thread
            if(!Main.trans[tid].terminate){

                lock.lock.readLock().lock();
                Main.g.removeEdge(tid, lock.tid);
                synchronized(this){
                lock.readers.add(tid);
                }//synchronized
            }//if isInturrupted
            else
                return;
        }
       else
        synchronized(this) {
              lock.lock.readLock().lock();
              lock.readers.add(tid);
      } // synchronized

    } // rl

    /*******************************************************************************
     * Acquire an exclusive/write lock on data object oid.
     * @param tid  the transaction id
     * @param oid  the data object id
     */
    void wl (int tid, int oid) throws InterruptedException
    {
         //type to determine the last lock type in order
         //to be able to remove the edges from waitfor graph
        int type = 0;
        MyLock lock = null;
        boolean wait = false;

        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                lock = locks.get(oid);             // find the lock
                if(lock != null && (lock.lock.isWriteLocked() || lock.readers.size() > 0))
                {
                    wait = true;
                }
                if(lock == null){
                    lock = new MyLock(tid);
                    lock.lock.writeLock().lock();
                    locks.put(oid,lock);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());        // lock not found, so oid is not locked;
            } // try
      }
         if (wait){
                System.out.println("Transaction " + tid + " is waiting..");
                if(lock.lock.isWriteLocked())
                    Main.g.addEdge(tid, lock.tid);
                else{
                    type = 1;
                    for(int reader : lock.readers)
                         Main.g.addEdge(tid, reader);
                    }//else

                            if(Main.g.hasCycle())
                            {
                                restart(tid);
                            }//if
           if(!Main.trans[tid].terminate){
                System.out.println("I'm waiting here in wl");
                lock.lock.writeLock().lock();
                System.out.println("Wakeup..");
                if(type == 0)
                    Main.g.removeEdge(tid, lock.tid);
                else
                    for(int reader : lock.readers)
                        Main.g.removeEdge(tid, reader);
                lock.tid = tid;
             }
            else
                return;

        }// if(wait) ==> for the lock to be released
        else 
            lock.lock.writeLock().lock();

    } // wl

    void restart(int tid){
     synchronized(this) {
        MyLock lock;
        List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList();
        for(int i : locks.keySet()){
           lock = locks.get(i);

               //lock.sem.release();
               if(lock.lock.isWriteLockedByCurrentThread()){

                   System.out.println("Transaction"+tid+" unlock object "+ i +" in order to restart");
                   lock.lock.writeLock().unlock();
                    System.out.println("number of write holders: " + lock.lock.writeLock().getHoldCount());
                    System.out.println("number of read holders: " + lock.lock.getReadHoldCount());
                    System.out.println("number of waiters: " + lock.lock.getQueueLength());
                   toRemove.add(i);

               }
           if(!lock.lock.isWriteLocked())
               if(lock.readers.contains(tid)){
                   // lock.numberOfReaders --;

                      System.out.println("Transaction"+tid+" unlock object "+ i +" in order to restart");
                      lock.readers.remove(lock.readers.indexOf(tid));
                      lock.lock.readLock().unlock();
                      System.out.println("number of write holders: " + lock.lock.getWriteHoldCount());
                      System.out.println("number of read holders: " + lock.lock.getReadHoldCount());
                      System.out.println("number of waiters: " + lock.lock.getQueueLength());
                      toRemove.add(i);  

                  }//if
        }//for
        for(int i = 0; i < toRemove.size() ; i ++)
            locks.remove(toRemove.get(i));
        Main.g.removeEdges(tid);

       // Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        Main.trans[tid].terminate = true;

        System.out.println("Transaction" + tid + " restarted");

        }//sync
    }

    /*******************************************************************************
     * Unlock/release the lock on data object oid.
     * @param tid  the transaction id
     * @param oid  the data object id
     */
    void ul (int tid, int oid)
    {
       MyLock lock = null;
        boolean error = false;
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                lock = locks.get(oid);                    // find the lock
                if( lock == null)
                    System.out.println("println: lock not found");

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("lock not found");   // lock not found
            } // try
        }//sync
            if((lock != null) && (lock.lock.isWriteLockedByCurrentThread())){

                      System.out.println("tid: " + tid + " unlock object: " + oid);
                      lock.lock.writeLock().unlock();
                      System.out.println("done with unlock");
                      System.out.println("number of write holders: " + lock.lock.writeLock().getHoldCount());
                      System.out.println("number of read holders: " + lock.lock.getReadHoldCount());
                      System.out.println("number of waiters: " + lock.lock.getQueueLength());
          }// if lock != null
            else
              if((lock != null) && (lock.readers.size()>0)){
                  if(lock.readers.contains(tid)){
                    lock.readers.remove(lock.readers.indexOf(tid));
                    lock.lock.readLock().unlock();
                    System.out.println("Transaction"+tid+" unlocked shared lock on object "+oid);
                    //System.out.println("number of write holders: " + lock.lock.readLock().);
                    System.out.println("number of read holders: " + lock.lock.getReadHoldCount());
                    System.out.println("number of waiters: " + lock.lock.getQueueLength());

                  }//if lock.readers
              }//if


        if (error) 
            System.out.println ("Error: ul: no lock for oid = " + oid + " found/owned");
    } // ul
```

Comment: Can you clean this up a bit and leave only the relevant lines of code? It's a little hard to read...

Comment: Which output do you get, and which output did you expect? Your example is not executable this way, so we can't try it out.

Comment: Also, you might want to use the `jstack` tool to have a look at the stack status of all your threads when they are stuck. It shows you which thread holds which locks, and which is waiting on which lock.

Comment: Paulo if u wanna see the executable code, I can send it to ur email, if u can send me ur email address to khaleefh@hotmail.com

Comment: I rolled back the edit because the original post was more telling of what the problem was.

Comment: I suggest you use ConcurrentHashMap and refactor out the synchronized block.  This way you only have one lock to worry about, and you won't get a deadlock.

Answer (score 4):

```
Method A:
...snip...
synchronized(this) {
    ...snip...
    lock.lock.readLock().lock();
    ...snip...
}

Method B:
...snip...
synchronized(this) {
    ...snip...
    lock.lock.readLock().unlock();
    ...snip...
}
```

The problem you are having is a deadlock from basically blocking on one synchronizer while holding another. When you call `Lock.lock()` inside of a `synchronized(this)` code block, the `Thread` will enter a `BLOCKING` state while continuing to hold the intrinsic lock on `this`. Since the Thread which actually holds the Lock as to obtain the intrinsic-lock on `this` and the intrinsic -lock will never be released, you have a deadlock.

For example:
Thread1 enters Method A, obtains a lock on `this`
Thread2 enters Method A, can't obtain `this` so blocks
Thread1 obtains Readlock
Thread1 releases `this`
Thread2 obtains `this`
Thread2 blocks waiting for Readlock
Thread1 enters Method B, can't obtain `this` so blocks
*deadlocked*

Answer (score 0):

also, don't forget about the non-happy path.  make sure to put your unlock() inside of a finally, otherwise if an exception gets thrown, unlock() is never called and you end up in deadlock.